# JavaScript loop through to check duplicate value

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I am having troubles trying to check if the date exists in the array.

```
 for(var i = 0; i< crisislist.length; i++){
        hazecounter = 1;
        if(crisislist[i].category == 1){
            if(crisislist[i].date != crisislist[i+1].date) {
                hazelabel.push(crisislist[i].date);
            }else{
                hazecounter++; 
            }
            hazedata.push(hazecounter);
        }
 }
```

The sample data for the date is:

```
["01-02-2017", "22-03-2017", "22-03-2017", "07-08-2017"]
```

And the expected output for hazelabel, hazedata should be:

hazelabel: ["01-02-2017", "22-03-2017", "07-08-2017"]
   hazedata: [1,2,1]

With the code above, when I check until the last element in the array and trying to make a comparison, it throw me an error message:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'date' of undefined
```

I think this is because when I reach the last element of array, and I try to find crisislist[I+1].date, it could not found and thus the error message.

Any idea how to fix this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't get it , need more code .

Comment: Can't you just check if `crisislist[i] + 1` is not `undefined` before accessing the `date` property?

Comment: you can write it simply like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40418507/javascript-filter-array-with-duplicate-dates. jsfiddle demo https://jsfiddle.net/u6u80zsa/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must access `crisislist[i+1].date` only when `i` doesn't point to the last element.

Also notice that to get the desired result, you need to move the `hazedata.push` inside the if block and put the initialisation of `hazecounter` in front of the loop.

```
var hazecounter = 1;
for (var i = 0; i< crisislist.length; i++) {
    if (crisislist[i].category == 1) {
        if (i == crisislist.length-1 || crisislist[i].date != crisislist[i+1].date) {
            hazelabel.push(crisislist[i].date);
            hazedata.push(hazecounter);
            hazeCounter = 1;
        } else {
            hazecounter++; 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks it works! I was thinking how to check for the last element.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to check till second last :

```
for(var i = 0; i< (crisislist.length-1); i++){
        hazecounter = 1;
        if(crisislist[i].category == 1){
            if(crisislist[i].date != crisislist[i+1].date) {
                hazelabel.push(crisislist[i].date);
                if (crisislist.length-2 == i)
                {
                    hazelabel.push(crisislist[i+1].date);
                }
            }else{
                hazecounter++; 
            }
            hazedata.push(hazecounter);
        }
 }
```

Comment: But that would ignore the last one?

Comment: just try out it will be compared with second last so it will not

Comment: compared, yes, but the last item is not looked at separately.

Answer (score 0):

Your if statement is going to be a problem.

```
if(crisislist[i].date != crisislist[i+1].date) {
```

You are accessing crisislist[i+1] in a loop that goes to < crisislist.length. That means that if you have an array of size 4, your loop will go until i = 3, but you are accessing i+1 from the array (crisislist[4]), which will be undefined.

Try changing your for loop to go to crisis.length-1

Answer (score 0):

Check that code. If you have any questions, add a comment :)  In my solution dates dont have to be sorted.

```
  </head>

<BODY>
<script>

function Something(date)
{
    this.date = date;
    this.category = 1;
}

var crisislist = [];
var hazelabel = [];
var hazedata = [];
crisislist[0] = new Something("01-02-2017");
crisislist[1] = new Something("22-03-2017");
crisislist[2] = new Something("22-03-2017");
crisislist[3] = new Something("07-08-2017");




 for(var i = 0; i< crisislist.length; i++){
    if(crisislist[i].category == 1)
    {
     if(!hazelabel[crisislist[i].date])
     {
         hazelabel[crisislist[i].date] = crisislist[i].date;
         hazedata[crisislist[i].date] = 1;
     }
     else
     {
         hazedata[crisislist[i].date]++;
     }
    }
 }

for(var key  in hazelabel)
{
console.log(hazelabel[key]);
console.log(hazedata[key]);  
}

</script>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```